# How to set a value in a select2 combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox, jquery-select2

I need to auto-fill a form that is using select2 comboboxes. The classic JS code `document.getElementById('id').value = 'value';` isn't working, nor do I wish to include jQuery for what should be a simple operation, unless absolutely unavoidable. Are there any JS alternatives to this problem ?

I have no control over the HTML, so changing the boxes isn't an option, unfortunately.

Comment: Why did you add the jQuery tag when you don't want to include jQuery?

Comment: Because select2 is a jquery component.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jquery` with select2 and must have `trigger('change')` same as :

```
$("#id").val(value).trigger('change');
```

Comment: That works, but the visible part of the combobox does not update. I still see the placeholder instead of the selected value, but when it is submitted, it holds the correct selected value. Any ideas ? I am not at all familiar with jQuery, I only code vanilla JS.

Comment: Never mind, it has nothing to do with jQuery. I just found out that my classic JS code does exactly the same thing. It sets and submits the selection correctly, but fails to display it onscreen.